# How can you define the exponential and logarithmic integrals in terms of the incomplete gamma function?

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma(0,x)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

For the Euler integral definition, it seems reasonable that $Ei(x)$ and $Li(x)$ can be expressed in terms of the incomplete gamma function, but the engine result shows a more complicated expression that just either of those functions. How can you express only $Ei(x)$ and $Li(x)$ in terms of just the incomplete gamma function?

Comment: These seem to be given in the linked Wikipedia pages.

Comment: No, it's not. They make vague tangential references for mabye particular values but do not give an explicit generalization that shows the final results for $Ei(x)$ and $Li(x)$. "i" in this instance is not $n=i$, $n$ is supposed to be an integer.

Comment: OK ! Now, I see your point.